# How to write an attribute name to the select query dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table including:

```
ID Name Period0Id Period1Id Period2Id
```

What I would like to receive data based on a user-defined parameter @check.
Lets assume:

```
declare @check int = 1;
```

In this case I need to get Period1Id value from the table. So I need to have something like that:

```
Select ID, Name, StatusId = Period + @check + Id  --  @check is the parameter
From mytable
```

However, my query is not working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table looks like it is not in first normal form.

Instead of three columns for Period0Id to Period2Id you could have a column for PeriodIndex with values of (0,1,2) and a single column for PeriodId and then it would be just a `WHERE PeriodIndex = @Check`

You can't select a column using string interpolation with a variable as you are attempting. You can use dynamic SQL to create the SQL String dynamically. Or simply hardcode the options if they all have the same dataype.

```
Select ID, 
       Name, 
       StatusId = CASE @Check WHEN 0 THEN Period0Id
                              WHEN 1 THEN Period1Id
                              WHEN 2 THEN Period2Id
                   END
From mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way that will create dynamic columns, which is essentially using your original query:

```
DECLARE @check VARCHAR = 1
DECLARE @sqlquery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlquery = N'SELECT ID, Name, StatusId = Period'+@check+'Id
                FROM mytable'
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlquery
```