# SQL: How to concatenate comparison operator in a query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm building a UI where user will have an option of entering different comparison operations such as >,<,>=,<=.

I need to reflect it in my query, so the `WHERE`clause in my query will look like this:

```
declare @number int
declare @operand varchar(2) = '>' --can be >, <, >=, <=

.....
WHERE amount` + operand + `@number`
.....
```

So, resulting piece would be `WHERE amount > @number`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set table name in dynamic sql query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678725/how-to-set-table-name-in-dynamic-sql-query)

Comment: You have to use dynamic. And be aware of SQL Injection attacks

Comment: Recommended to have a case statement if you only have the comparison operators commented in your code... primarily because of SQL injection.

Comment: You could also take a look at a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840979/how-to-write-an-attribute-name-to-the-select-query-dynamically/37841275#37841275)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
declare @number int = 4
declare @operand varchar(2) = '>' --can be >, <, >=, <=

exec('select * from TableName
WHERE amount  ' + @operand + ' ' + @number)
```

Answer (score 0):

This opens you up to SQL code injection.  Also to concatenate an INT you have to set as varchar, but it will evaluate as INT in the actual statement.

```
declare @number varchar(max) = '1'
declare @operand varchar(2) = '>' --can be >, <, >=, <=
declare @Where varchar(max)


SET @Where = 'WHERE amount ' +  @operand + ' ' + @number

SELECT @Where
```